# Bad call of method

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2010

Here is part of my html file:

```
$('#btnMyButton').click(function () {
        alert("message");
        ajaxPost("Service1.svc/json/GetMethod", { "humanName": "anna" }, anotherMethod);
    });
```

And here is the method being called:

```
public Human GetCustomer(string humanName)
    {
        Human x = new Human();
        x.name = humanName;
        return x;
    }
```

But I got error - 400 bad request! How to fix it?

The body of the anotherMethod method is:

```
  var txt = JSON.stringify(msg);
        log("Result = " + txt);
```

Here is the name of the method:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Human GetMethod(string humanName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to consume a JSON enabled WCF web service you may try the following:

```
$('#btnMyButton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Service1.svc/json/GetMethod',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ humanName: 'anna' }),
        success: function(result) {
            // TODO: do something with the results
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method shown here is natively built into modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you might need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script.

Comment: @Srcee, well, you will have to provide more details about your service. Does it accept POST methods? Does it accept JSON requests? How is it configured? ... Many details are necessary before your question becomes anything close to answerable. Right now we can only be guessing.

Comment: @Srcee, details about your service.

Comment: @Srcee, what about your web.config? What is the url that the endpoint is configured to listen to?

Comment: If the method's parameter and return type are Human, everything is fine. If the input type is string, it's bad :(
That's why I think web.config isn't the problem.